# Knowledge building

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, management

I'm working as a R&D Engineer (Infotainment and Telematics) with a leading automotive products manufacturer. I have joined recently and although I have an industrial experience of 2 years, I have no previous experience in automotive domain. I have worked extensively on Linux (<strike>Android</strike>) platform (from developing applications to compiling and porting kernels), web applications and embedded hardware (ARM based boards and processors).

My problem is, currently, I have not any project going on and my manager says that I should keep "building knowledge". It was speculated that I'll be working on HTML5 and Qt and I've been "building knowledge" on the same. I haven't been given a specific road map or tasks and I'm working randomly.

My question is, since I have no previous experience of automotive domain, what topics/subjects/technologies must I focus on to get more experience/knowledge specific to automotive domain? I don't mind if a particular topic/subject/technology is unrelated to Infotainment. I'm particularly interested in automotive electronics.

PS: Apologies for the tags but I knew not what tag would befit the question.

Comment: This is probably a question best asked of your manager.

Comment: I did and got a perfunctory reply.

Comment: Well, in that case it wouldn't hurt to try to gain an understanding of what the company actually does and how they fit into the automotive industry.  Then from that context, think about the project you have been led to believe you'll be working on, and how the suggested technologies fit with that.

Comment: that is a good suggestion and I too am thinking similarly. The thing is, I'm not gaining any new experience/knowledge and basically brushing up things I already know.

Comment: That _is_ something that you should highlight to your manager.

Comment: Are there other teams around you getting on with projects? Can you get your manager to get some of the documentation for those projects, so you have an understanding of something that the company is actually doing? If there's no documentation, can you offer your time in writing some, as that'll be a learning experience? It really sounds like relating to a current project would be more helpful than abstract reading.

Comment: Find the most talkative manager and ask them - I guarantee that somewhere near you in the management structure, there's a manager who *loves* to talk :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you the only R&D engineer in this company?

If not then maybe take a look at what your colleagues are working on, and any past projects, to get to know the way this company works.

If you are, then maybe take a look at competing companies products.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know the specifics yet, consider learning HTML5 through tutorials and building a personal Web project, related to your industry and what you're best guess is that you'll be doing (but distant enough that you wouldn't need permission from your employer).

Here are two short YouTube videos to get you going:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bWPMSSsVdPk (HTML)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0afZj1G0BIE (CSS)

[Sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is a great code editor with a free trial, but there are plenty of others.

With an investment of just 20 minutes a day, you'll make great progress in a month. If you get stuck on a question, [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) probably has the answer. Good luck!